Speed of interpolation of a four-dimensional array in OpenModelica
During modeling, I encountered a task where I needed to obtain a value dependent on three variables. Creating a polynomial of sufficient accuracy turned out to be impossible. Therefore, I decided to create a four-dimensional array and obtain values from it through linear interpolation, as I did previously in the Wolfram Mathematica environment.
First, I used the ExternData library to load the .csv file into the openmodelica environment and wrote an algorithm that forms an array of data:
function loaddata

input String fileName;
input Integer nrow;
input Integer ncol;

input Integer nx;
input Integer ny;
input Integer nz;

output Real array[nx,ny,nz];

protected

  ExternData.CSVFile dataSource(
  fileName = fileName,
  nHeaderLines = 1
) annotation(Placement(transformation(origin = {-56, 56}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}})));

Real dataarr[nrow,ncol];
Real string[nz];
Real list[ny,nz];

algorithm

dataarr := dataSource.getRealArray2D(nrow, ncol) annotation(HideResult = true);

for i in 1:nx loop
    for j in 1:ny loop
        for k in 1:nz loop
        string[k] := dataarr[(i*ny-(ny-j)),k];
        end for;
    list[j,:] := string;
    string[nz] := 0;
    end for;
array[i,:,:] := list;
list[ny,nz] := 0;
end for;


end loaddata;

&&
model loadcsv

MYLIB.Property.LoadProp pack;

parameter String filelocation = "Z:/storage/OpenModelica/PropLibrary/out.csv";

parameter Integer nx = 10;
parameter Integer ny = 10;
parameter Integer nz = 51;

parameter Integer row = 100;
parameter Integer col = nz;

parameter Real arr[:,:,:] = pack.loaddata(filelocation, row, col, nx, ny, nz) annotation(HideResult = true);

equation

end loadcsv;

Then I wrote a function to linearly interpolate the array:
function intarr
  input Real x1;
  input Real y1;
  input Real z1;
  input Real data[:, :, :];
  output Real xyz;
  
protected
  Real yz11, yz21, xx1, yz12, yz22, xx2;
  parameter Real A[:,:,:];
  Integer ii, kk, jj, lenx, leny, lenz;
algorithm

  A := data;
  
  lenx := size(A, 1);
  leny := size(A, 2);
  lenz := size(A, 3);
    
//Визначаємо дві сторінки що є опорними точками до нашого значення тиску
  for i in 1:lenx - 1 loop
    if x1 >= A[i, leny, lenz] and x1 <= A[i + 1, leny, lenz] then
      ii := i;
    end if;
  end for;
//Визначаємо опорні рядки
  for j in 1:leny - 2 loop
    if y1 <= A[ii, j, lenz] and y1 >= A[ii, j + 1, lenz] then
      jj := j;
    end if;
  end for;
  
//Визначаємо опорні стовпчики
  for k in 1:lenz - 2 loop
    if z1 <= A[ii, leny, k] and z1 >= A[ii, leny, k + 1] then
      kk := k;
    end if;
  end for;
  
//Виконуємо білінійну інтерполяцію першої опорної сторінки (точки)
  yz11 := A[ii, jj, kk] + (z1 - A[ii, leny, kk])*((A[ii, jj, kk + 1] - A[ii, jj, kk])/(A[ii, leny, kk + 1] - A[ii, leny, kk]));
  yz21 := A[ii, jj + 1, kk] + (z1 - A[ii, leny, kk])*((A[ii, jj + 1, kk + 1] - A[ii, jj + 1, kk])/(A[ii, leny, kk + 1] - A[ii, leny, kk]));
  xx1 := yz11 + (y1 - A[ii, jj, lenz])*((yz21 - yz11)/(A[ii, jj + 1, lenz] - A[ii, jj, lenz]));
//Виконуємо білінійну інтерполяцію другої опорної сторінки (точки)
  yz12 := A[ii + 1, jj, kk] + (z1 - A[ii + 1, leny, kk])*((A[ii + 1, jj, kk + 1] - A[ii + 1, jj, kk])/(A[ii + 1, leny, kk + 1] - A[ii + 1, leny, kk]));
  yz22 := A[ii + 1, jj + 1, kk] + (z1 - A[ii + 1, leny, kk])*((A[ii + 1, jj + 1, kk + 1] - A[ii + 1, jj + 1, kk])/(A[ii + 1, leny, kk + 1] - A[ii + 1, leny, kk]));
  xx2 := yz12 + (y1 - A[ii + 1, jj, lenz])*((yz22 - yz12)/(A[ii + 1, jj + 1, lenz] - A[ii + 1, jj, lenz]));
//Виконуємо лінійну інтерполяцію між двома опорними сторінками (точками)
  xyz := xx1 + (x1 - A[ii, leny, lenz])*((xx2 - xx1)/(A[ii + 1, leny, lenz] - A[ii, leny, lenz]));
end intarr;


Then, accordingly, I created a model in which I load a file, form an array and, if necessary, access the array to interpolate it and get the value I need. My array has the size x=37, y=164, z=51 and, accordingly, 309468 values. When I use a smaller array, everything is calculated quickly and well. When using the full array, my simple model can be calculated in 20 minutes. The implementation of a similar algorithm in the  Wolfram Mathematica environment is performed in a matter of seconds.
model test_load
  parameter Real Pk0 = 40, kmi = 3, ARi = 290, Tgin0= 293, Toin0 =90;
  Real IdAr;
  parameter Real arrIdAr[:, :, :] = Id_ch.arr annotation(
    HideResult = true);
 
  Property.LoadProp.loadcsv Id_ch(nx = /*4*/10, ny = 164, nz = 51, row = /*656*/1640, col = 51, filelocation = "Z:/storage/OpenModelica/PropLibrary/out.csv") annotation(
    Placement(transformation(origin = {-90, 90}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}})));
 
equation
  IdAr = MYLIB.Property.IntFunc.intarr(Pk0, kmi, ARi, arrIdAr);
end test_load;

I don't quite understand everything, because I started learning openmodelica only a month ago and I hope for your advice.
My questions are:

Is low performance the result of incorrect implementation? If so how can I fix it?
If the implementation is correct and this is a problem of the openmodelica environment, how should I interpolate the data array?
Is it possible to implement something similar without using the external data library, but using only the built-in functions?
Since I own  Wolfram Mathematica, can I use some API to perform interpolation in mathematica notebook and take only the result from there?

Sorry for the mistakes in the text, English is not my native language.
Thank you very much in advance for your answers.

I suspect that the main problem is with the translation.
Are there methods to speed up the translation and which settings are better to set?

I would avoid declaring parameter Real arrIdAr[:, :, :] = Id_ch.arr; as that will expand into scalar elements. Create this array just in the function and return just one value from it.

Welcome Volodymyr! I am a bit confused: what is the fonction intarr2D you are calling in the test model? It doesn't have the same arguments as intarr you provided.

Use instantiate model to see how your model looks after translation. Because you have such a big parameter array the C code generated will be quite big and compilation will take a while.

Welcome, Adrian. Thank you very much for the advice. I checked all the models and functions and reduced the number of repeated declarations of arrays. This significantly reduced time of translation the model and the calculation began to go faster. I implemented this model the way you saw in the question because I was gradually building this model and accumulating errors.

Hi, Clement. I apologize for confusing you. The fact is that several functions were called in my model and there were many commented functions. I removed the extra data in order not to confuse you, but it turned out the other way around :-) . I will edit the question. Thank you.
